# Como listar todos os parâmetros de um relatório automaticamente no SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, parâmetros, reporting-services

**Problema**

Preciso gerar um LOG de uso de relatórios com o usuário, nome do relatório, data de uso e parâmetros selecionados. A maioria dos campos foi obtido usando os *Built-In Fiels*.  Entretanto, não consigo obter uma string com todos os parâmetros do relatório (**nome e valor**).

É possível produzir esta string com expressões de concatenação, mas não é muito viável no meu caso. Preciso aplicar isso a todos os relatórios da organização e fazer a concatenação de vários campos demanda tempo e podem ocorrer erros de atenção facilmente. Assim, busco uma forma automática de listar todos os parâmetros.

**Tentativas realizadas**

- *Utilizar a tabela executionlog3 do SQL* : o nome do usuário que é registrado não é correto por causa de uma configuração local do servidor.
- *Utilizar alguns scripts no Custom Code como [este](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/SSRS-Custom-code-to-f73d610d)* : Estes tipos de scripts necessitam de permissões de segurança FullTrust, o que a instituição não está disposta a dar.
- *Tentar fazer um loop na collection Parameters via Custom Code* : Isso não é permitidoo - "You cannot use a Visual Basic For Each construct to step through the collection." - [Link da documentação](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(v=sql.100).aspx)

**Solução proposta**

A forma menos custosa que consegui fazer foi passando os nomes dos parâmetros por uma string para o custom code.

Expressão

```html
=Code.PrintParam("param1 param2")
```

Função VB

```html
Public Function PrintParam(ByVal paramslist As String) As String  
    Dim params = split(paramslist)
    Dim final as String = ""
    For Each param As String In params
        final &= param & " = " & Report.Parameters(param).Value & "; "
    Next
    return final
End Function
```

Resultado:

```html
param1 = 10; param2 = 20;
```